# How to create Image Button in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

Please let us know how to create Image Button in Xamarin.Forms, we aren't using the story board.

Environment : Xamarin Studio on Mac

Comment: In xamrin form button has Image property..you can set like this... <Button Image="logo.jpg"/>

Answer (score 8):

A lot of ways, like this one:

```
var button = new Image { ... }; // make your image your button should be
button.GestureRecognizers.Add (new TapGestureRecognizer (sender => {
  // Do whatever you want to do when its tapped
  button.Opacity = 0.6;
  button.FadeTo (1);
}));
```

Or you can even use Xamarin forms labs:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

Or like @Gerald Versluis say:

With image property of the button.

```
Image="logo.jpg"
```

Comment: With image property of button,  text comes next to image. What to do to make text on the image.

Comment: Is it posible to do this in xaml?

Answer (score 2):

Actually

> Xamarin.Forms.TapGestureRecognizer.TapGestureRecognizer(System.Action)
>
> > is obsolete: 'Obsolete in 1.0.2. Use Command instead

Try like this one:

```
  var CallButton = new Image { Source = "call.png" };
      CallButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
             {
              Command=new Command(()=> {
                // Do whatever you want to do when its tapped
                  })
              });
```

For More info, Check the following link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e04e9a/xamarin-forms-image-button-recipe/

Comment: @user1027076 ..check this solution